# Which R-Squared formula is used in carets' k-fold-cross validation function

Tags: r, cross-validation, caret

I am currently trying to implement a linear model and calculate some out-of-sample accuracy metrics while using k-fold-cross validation. I try to do this using R's caret package, so this question might be a bit specific.

In many papers I read that the out-of-sample error is computed as:
[image]

What stood out to me, is that the mean of the response variable is taken out of the training set, even though we are calculating the out-of-sample error. Two questions regarding this:

1.) Is this the usual approach to calculate the out-of-sample R-squared? I have also seen some papers, where the out-of-sample R-squared is calculated with the mean of y taken out of the test set.

2.) As before mentioned I am using carets k-fold-cross validation and it reports the R-Squared value for the out-of-sample sets. How is this calculated though? With the mean of y out of the training or the test set?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi! Have you found out how to calculate the R2 for cross-validation? Need some help here.